# Dropzone JS 6 beta 1 uploadMultiple not triggered

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm having troubles in setting dropzone JS in a pre existing form, in which I have to load multiple files.

I have an existing asp.net form (with an antiforgery token), and I've set up the Dropzone as follows:

```
 const dz = new Dropzone(".dropzonecreate", {
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
        previewpreviewsContainer: "#dropzonePreview",
        clickable: "#dropzonePreview",
        url: "/InserzioneMoto/Create",
        // The setting up of the dropzone
        init: function () {
            var myDropzone = this;
            document.getElementById('InsertInserzione').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
            //Even with two or more files this got triggered
            this.on("sending", function (data, xhr, formData) {
                var data = $('#dZUpload').serializeArray();
                $.each(data, function (key, el) {
                    formData.append(el.name, el.value);
                });
            });
           //This never get triggered
            this.on("sendingMultiple", function (data, xhr, formData) {
                var data = $('#dZUpload').serializeArray();
                $.each(data, function (key, el) {
                  formData.append(el.name, el.value);
                });
            });
        },
        maxFilesize: 100,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg, .jpg, .png",
        dictDefaultMessage: "<strong>Trascinare i file o cliccare per sfogliare</strong><br/>sono ammessi solo .jpeg o .jpg fino a 100 MB",
        dictFallbackMessage: "Il browser non supporta il trascinamento di files, usare: chrome, ie, opera, safari, firefox o edge",
        dictFileTooBig: "File Troppo Grande ({{filesize}}). Il limite è fissato a {{maxFilesize}}.",
        dictInvalidFileType: "Il tipo di file non è fra quelli permessi. sono ammessi solo file .jpeg, .jpg, .png",
        dictResponseError: "Server non disponibile. codice errore {{statusCode}}",
        dictRemoveFile: "Rimuovi file"
    });
```

I have an existing div `#DropzonePreview` that'll contain the loaded files until the request has been sent. I've set `uploadMultiple`, with the `parallelUploads` and `maxFiles`. Yet it still sends file one by one (with the same antiforgery token, so the request can't be fullfilled).

If I have one single file the request works flawlessly and I can get the file from `Request.Files`.

Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance.